# My baked normals only appear in material view but not rendered view?

Tags: normals

My baked normals seem to only be appearing in material view and not rendered view. I have no idea why it would be set to this. Unless its something simpler than I'm making it. Please help!

[image]<<< with render attempt
[image]<<< in material view
not sure whats going on here. Would appreciate some sage wisdom

Comment: Hi. Please upload your images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, not sure what was going wrong but i loaded to an earlier saved file and it works just fine. Not super happy with how it turned out...but such is life!